# Level Editor and Event Editors in 3D games

Tags: c++, scripting

I've been reading around, but I couldn't find a concrete answer to this. I'm programming a 3d game that is going to require a more high level view of editing in terms of level design and scripting events. Not so much level design than being able to import characters and events ala more visual IDE game developing programs (Unity, game maker, rpg maker). How would I go about achieving this? I assume it'll require a scripting integration, firstly, to allow real time editing, such as with Lua or C# (I'll be programming this in C++ mostly). And I also would like to know is this something that is designed separate from the main application. Aka, whatever you design in this editor, you can "export" it in a formal readable by the main game program.

Comment: A scripting engine isn't entirely necessary for real-time editing, the various controls and what not could be coded directly in C++. You could even implement the editor as part of the game itself that would add various buttons and controls to the user interface to enable editing to take place.

Comment: Yes, I've seen something like that in videos of people with their own editors, able to switch from building to playing with a click of a button. That's the kind of functionality I would like.